# hide Div by using "display:none" of div on asp.net page

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net

I am displaying data which fetch by calling webservice in jquery with my below code.

```
                <div class="col text-right text-nowrap" data-bind="TypeCode"></div>
```

I need to hide the div on basis of value of data field , like if TypeCode = "A" then it should hide the div.

I tried like below code but its giving error "Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'TypeCode' does not exist in the current context"

```
            <div class="row" style='<%# TypeCode=="A"? "display:none;" : string.Empty %>'>
```

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: _"but its giving error"_ - What error are you getting?

Comment: @phuzi It says "Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'TypeCode' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Is `TypeCode` a JavaScript or C# variable?